# How to fix React.js project generated by command line so that IDEA recognizes JSX in JS files?

Tags: reactjs, intellij-idea

I generated a React.js app using command line "npx create-react-app my-app" and then opened (File / Open) the generated project in IntelliJ Idea but Idea does not recognize JSX syntax in *.js files - see image below. When I generate a new React project using Idea menu New / Project / JavaScript / React, it's fine. How can I fix the project generated by the command line please? I'm using IntelliJ Idea Ultimate 2020.

[image: Project generated by commandline]

Comment: You should try VSCode. It has better support in my opinion. Rename the file to *.jsx. Return a single parent. Put a `<>` and `</>` at parent level wrapping all the jsx.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should wrap your return code to React Fragment

```
<>
  <h1>My Todos...</h1>
  <div>Some content...</div>
</>
```

Answer (score 0):

In **Settings | Languages & Frameworks | JavaScript**, make sure to set **JavaScript Language version** to either **React JSX** (when using IDE version < `2020.3`) or **ECMAScript 6+** (IDEA 2020.3 or higher)

I'd also recommend re-opening the project after changing the language version. If it doesn't work immediately, try invalidating caches (**File > Invalidate caches, Invalidate and Restart**)

Comment: Thank you for your reply! I checked the settings mentioned above and executed 'Invalidate and Restart' but the issue still persists.

Comment: what language version do you have chosen there, what IDE version do you work with?

Comment: It's IntelliJ Idea Ultimate 2020.3.3 and the selected language is ECMAScript 6+.

Comment: Please check if you have nested `.idea` folders in your project structure

Comment: Checked, no nested .idea folders, there's only one .idea folder in my project structure.